/boot partition too small again on debian testing/trixie
In the current testing debian distribution (13/trixie), I ends up with a /boot partition of 500Mo.
The current kernel initrd file inside /boot being 250 Mo, I can't upgrade the kernel anymore.
/dev/sda1                        ext2      455M  269M  162M  63% /boot

Why the /boot ends up so small and how to upgrade the kernel in this setting without breaking the system (i.e removing the current running kernel) ?

If you are unhappy with the defaults you can always choose a different size for /boot at install time. That said, I'm surprised your initrd is so large; on a fresh install of trixie, my initrd image is only 16MB.

might have to use fdisk and then resize2fs

Actually, resizing the initrd might do the trick as answered here

Thanks for you suggestions guys. Indeed using the option MODULES=dep divided the size of the initrd.img by 10. I hope  that at next reboot, everything will be ok though

for reference, having used RHEL-7 and RHEL-8 in enterprise environment for last 10 years, I have always done

1GB    /boot
100MB  /boot/efi
Have never gotten over 10% used on /boot/efi
My current rhel-8 system is 40% full for /boot

recognize that /boot is a separate partition.  As such you can simply modify /etc/fstab to point to a new location [disk] for the boot partition.
So if you have no space left on your current disk then simplest option off top of my head is to get a second disk (small ssd $20 amazon) and format it with one partition of desired size, then lsblk -o size,fstype,model,name,uuid to get the UUID of that partition and use that for /boot. in /etc/fstab.
First mount it as /newboot and cp -rp /boot/* /newboot/.  Then umount them and remount newboot as /boot with it's UUID identified via lsblk.
Could /boot be a usb stick, probably.
Also peruse through /boot/grub and identify if there's any reference to the old /boot UUID and update for the new boot disk.  i am not familiar enough with grub if some things under there also need to be changed.
https://www.debian.org/releases/trixie/

This release started as a copy of bookworm, and is currently in a state called "testing". This means that things should not break as badly as in unstable or experimental distributions

um yeah, don't make /boot 500mb. consider making it 1gb minimum, maybe 2gb until you have confidence over time that is a good size choice... like I can say 1gb is for /boot on RHEL/CentOS/Rocky.

Thank you for your suggestion @ron
